# How can I get the last items from a nested array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested

I was struggling to get the last object item from a nested array. I tried to implement flatMap, flat, filter, and splice. However, I can not still get the expected array.

```
const array = [
  [
    {
      total_cases: 18,
    },
    {
      total_cases: 32,
    },
    {
      total_cases: 7,
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      total_cases: 4,
    },
    {
      total_cases: 52,
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      total_cases: 68,
    },
  ],
];
```

I have an array like the above. How can I get only the last-object item into a new array?

**Expected new array should be like this:**

```
[7, 52, 68]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.at()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at) method.  Negative parametr count back from the last item in the array. So `.at(-1)` return the last array's element.

```js
const array=[[{total_cases:18},{total_cases:32},{total_cases:7}],[{total_cases:4},{total_cases:52}],[{total_cases:68}]];

const result = array.map(e => e.at(-1).total_cases);

console.log(...result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is best if you can guarantee a modern browser

Answer (score 3):

**Edit** based on changes to question.

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to select only the last element of each nested array, then [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to flatten the array and `map` again to select the `total_cases` values:

```js
const array = [
  [ 
    { total_cases: 18 },
    { total_cases: 32 },
    { total_cases: 7 },
  ],
  [ 
    { total_cases: 4 },
    { total_cases: 52 },
  ],
  [ 
    { total_cases: 68 },
  ],
];

const result = array
  .map(a => a.slice(a.length - 1))
  .flat(1)
  .map(o => o.total_cases)
  
console.log(result)
```

**Original Answer**

You can [flatten](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) the array, [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) it based on the `date` value and then use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to extract the `total_cases` values:

```js
const array = [
  [
    {
      date: "2020-02-25",
      total_cases: 18,
    },
    {
      date: "2020-02-26",
      total_cases: 32,
    },
    {
      date: "last-object",
      total_cases: 7,
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      date: "2020-02-26",
      total_cases: 4,
    },
    {
      date: "last-object",
      total_cases: 52,
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      date: "last-object",
      total_cases: 68,
    },
  ],
];

const result = array
  .flat(1)
  .filter(o => o.date == 'last-object')
  .map(o => o.total_cases)
  
console.log(result)
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I edited the question. We shouldn't use the date items.

Comment: @ffcabbar please see my edit. I've added code which doesn't rely on the `date` items.